# how to check exist value attribute with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to check value of attribute html tag and if that element not exist with value of attribute append certain element in my html.

for example I have many li tags like this:

```
<ul id="friend-list">
    <li id="1"></li>
    <li id="2"></li>
    <li id="3"></li>
    <li id="4"></li>
    <li id="5"></li>
    <li id="6"></li>
</ul>
```

I want when click on any li run this jQuery code and append one element :

**append element :**

```
var conversation ='<div class="conversation stream" id='+ conversationID +'><div class="timeline"><ul class="all-msg"><li class="me typing"><div id="chat-text" contenteditable="true"></div><div id="upload-f"></div><div id="upload-p"></div><div id="chat-arrow"></div></li></ul></div></div>';
$('body').append(conversation);
```

**jQuery code:**

```
$(document).on('click','#friend-list li',function(){
    var getID = $(this).attr('id');
    var conversationID = 'Conver-' + getID;
    console.log(conversationID);


    if(/* don't exist element with attribute and value*/){
        // append that element

        var conversation ='<div class="conversation stream" id='+ conversationID +'><div class="timeline"><ul class="all-msg"><li class="me typing"><div id="chat-text" contenteditable="true"></div><div id="upload-f"></div><div id="upload-p"></div><div id="chat-arrow"></div></li></ul></div></div>';
        $('body').append(conversation);
    }

});
```

so I want first check exist that I want append it. if this element not exist so append this Otherwise don't append this.

thanks a lot guys.

Comment: have you tired `if(conversationID.length)` for does not exists `if(conversationID.length == 0)`

Comment: what about `.length` ?

Comment: my friend I want check that exist one element in several element???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to check whether an element with the converssationID exists

```
$(document).on('click','#friend-list li',function(){
    var getID = $(this).attr('id');
    var conversationID = 'Conver-' + getID;
    console.log(conversationID);

    if(!$('#' + conversationID).length) {   
        var conversation ='<div class="conversation stream" id='+ conversationID +'><div class="timeline"><ul class="all-msg"><li class="me typing"><div id="chat-text" contenteditable="true"></div><div id="upload-f"></div><div id="upload-p"></div><div id="chat-arrow"></div></li></ul></div></div>';
        $('body').append(conversation);
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8FLmW/)

Note: You are appending elements with id `chat-text` and `upload-f` to every conversation which is invalid since ID should be unique in a document

Answer (score 2):

For checking element exists or not you can use `.length`.

```
.length will return number of elements in the jQuery object.
```

So code would looks like below.

```
if(conversationID.length)
```

for does not exists

```
if(conversationID.length == 0)
```

You can also use `.size()` but its deprecated.

Comment: length of `conversationID` will always be a non zero value because it is a string

Answer (score 1):

When you use jQuery to grab something, it returns an array of the results. If it can't find anything, it won't throw an error, it will simply give you back an empty array.

So, if the length of the jQuery object (which is an array) is `zero` then there are no matched elements to be found on this page at this time:

```
    $(document).on('click','#friend-list li',function(){
    var getID = $(this).attr('id');
    var conversationID = 'Conver-' + getID;
    console.log(conversationID);


    if($('#' + conversationID ).length > 0){
        // append that element

        var conversation ='<div class="conversation stream" id='+ conversationID +'><div class="timeline"><ul class="all-msg"><li class="me typing"><div id="chat-text" contenteditable="true"></div><div id="upload-f"></div><div id="upload-p"></div><div id="chat-arrow"></div></li></ul></div></div>';
        $('body').append(conversation);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('click','#friend-list li',function(){
    var getID = $(this).attr('id');
    var conversationID = 'Conver-' + getID;
    console.log(conversationID);


    if($('#' + conversationID ) == false){
        // append that element

        var conversation ='<div class="conversation stream" id='+ conversationID +'><div class="timeline"><ul class="all-msg"><li class="me typing"><div id="chat-text" contenteditable="true"></div><div id="upload-f"></div><div id="upload-p"></div><div id="chat-arrow"></div></li></ul></div></div>';
        $('body').append(conversation);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jquery given below..

```
$('#friend-list li').on('click',function(){  
    var getID = $(this).attr('id');
    var conversationID = 'Conver-' + getID;
    console.log(conversationID);


    if($('#'+conversationID).length == 0){
        // append that element

        var conversation ='<div class="conversation stream" id='+ conversationID +'><div class="timeline"><ul class="all-msg"><li class="me typing"><div id="chat-text" contenteditable="true"></div><div id="upload-f"></div><div id="upload-p"></div><div id="chat-arrow"></div></li></ul></div></div>';
        $('body').append(conversation);
    }

    });
```

In Jquery `.length` work for `check if exist or not. If not exist then it will return 0 value else more then 0`

Please look into given url...

http://jsfiddle.net/6G633/